# Printing patterns in java

Tags: java

I want to create a pattern in java that looks something like this->

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

(the number of stars depend on number entered by user.)

I know the first half half (increasing order), but please tell me how to make the rest half (decreasing order).
Thanks.

Here is my code for first part->

```
int y = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
for (x = 0; x <= y; x++) {
    jTextField2.setText(jTextField2.getText() + "*");
    jTextArea1.append(jTextField2.getText() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Count down instead of up?

Comment: Hi.. In the above example.. the "y" value is 5 rit?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hlo. Buddy.. try this code

```
int y = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
for (x = 0,z=0; x <= (y+y-1); x++) {
   if(x<=y){
     z++;
   }else{
    z--;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<=z;i++){
     jTextField2.setText(jTextField2.getText() + "*");
   }
   jTextArea1.append(jTextField2.getText() + "\n");
}
```

This will print the complete pattern

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that:

```
int y = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
for(x = y; x>=0; x--){
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < x ; i++) {
         s += "*";
    }
    jTextField2.setText(s);
    jTextArea1.append(jTextField2.getText()+"\n");
}
```

Note that if performance matters, you'd use a [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

I assume you don't want to use external libraries. Guava's [Strings.repeat](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#repeat) woul be a better solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

for decreasing order

```
for (x = y; x >= 0; x--) {
    jTextField2.setText(jTextField2.getText() + "*");
    jTextArea1.append(jTextField2.getText() + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, i hope this will be use ful

```
    int v = 1;
    int totStars = 20;

    for (int i = 1; i >= 0; i+=v) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        if(i >= totStars){
            v = -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), you could use this code:

```
int y = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
for(x = 0; x<=y; x++){
    String s = String.repeat("*", x);
    jTextArea1.append(s+"\n");
}
for(x = y; x>=0; x--){
    String s = String.repeat("*", x);
    jTextArea1.append(s+"\n");
}
```

This solution is more straightforward, but it does require an external library

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution which is worth taking the time to figure out how it works:

```
public void tristar(int n) {
    tristar(n, "");
}

public void tristar(int n, String stars) {
    if (n == 1) {
        System.out.println(stars + "*");
    } else {
        System.out.println(stars + "*");
        tristar(n-1, stars + "*");
        System.out.println(stars + "*");
    }
}
```